# Sending object to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to send value to MainActivity to HomeFragment. I created new project with bottom navigation, I dowland data from firebase in main activity, I need to send that data to HomeFragment after dowland it from firebase. I used bundle for that but I could not do it. How can I solve this?

Thanks

This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String age= "12";
String şifre;

ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);
    firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    getDatafromFireBase();




    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);








}


public String getMyData(){
    return şifre;
}


public void getDatafromFireBase(){

    DocumentReference documentReference=(DocumentReference) firebaseFirestore.collection("Şifre").document("Şifre");
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (error!=null){

            }
            if (value!=null){

                Map<String,Object> map=value.getData();
                Number şifre1=(Number) value.get("Şifre");
                şifre=String.valueOf(şifre1);

                HomeFragment homeFragment=new HomeFragment();


                System.out.println(şifre+"98");

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Şifre",şifre);
                homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);








            }
        }
    });



}


}
```

And this is my HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
String name;
ArrayList<String> list2;
String şifre;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    list2=new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());



}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);

    textView.setText(name);

    String deneme = getArguments().getString("Şifre");

    textView.setText(deneme);
    System.out.println(deneme);


    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}
}
```

Comment: why not using a ViewModel and get your Data with the observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fragment is already created the `onCreateView()` method is called only once when you attach the fragment,
what does `getArgumens()` is not called when you recive data from you Activity.

So in this case I suggest you use the **ViewModel** to be able to communicate with your Fragment.

First you need to add this [Dependencie](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies) in your buid.gradel :

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1"
```

Then create a class that extends **ViewModel** :

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class LiveDeneme extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void addDeneme(String deneme) {
        mutableLiveData.setValue(deneme);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getDeneme() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

On your Activity initialize the **ViewModel** inside you `onCreate()` method :

```
private LiveDeneme provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        provider = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LiveDeneme.class);

        /*
        Rest of your Code
         */
    }
```

And when you send Data use it like below :

```
public void getDatafromFireBase(){

    DocumentReference documentReference=(DocumentReference) firebaseFirestore.collection("Şifre").document("Şifre");
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if (error!=null){

            }
            if (value!=null){

                Map<String,Object> map=value.getData();
                Number şifre1=(Number) value.get("Şifre");
                şifre=String.valueOf(şifre1);
                // send the data with this line 
                provider.addDeneme(sifre);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

And finaly to recive the data from your Fragment use the Observer like below :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);

    textView.setText(name);
    
    LiveDeneme liveDeneme = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LiveDeneme.class);

    liveDeneme.getDeneme().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String deneme) {
            textView.setText(deneme);
        }
    });
    

    return root;
}
```

### Update

For sending an `ArrayList<String>` your **ViewModel** class should like this :

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LiveDeneme extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();


    public void addDeneme(ArrayList<String> deneme) {
        mutableLiveData.setValue(deneme);
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<String>> getDeneme() {
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

then to send this list from your activity you just do this :

```
provider.addDeneme(yourList)
```

And finaly te recive this list in your fragment :

```
LiveDeneme liveDeneme = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(LiveDeneme.class);
    
liveDeneme.getDeneme().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ArrayList<String> strings) {
                    for (String s : strings) {
                        System.out.println(s); // here I print all the element of the list 
                    }
                }
            });
```

For more information please check the offcial [Documenation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: How can i send ArrayList<String> just like this method. Foe example i dowland arraylist with using CollectionReferance from Firebase. How can I pass to fragment

Comment: just change the `private final MutableLiveData<String> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();` to `private final MutableLiveData<ArrayList<YourObject>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();` and also  change the method to get and set

Comment: I could not do. Can you write like you did before please? I am new in Android Studio and Java, it should be String ArrayList

Comment: i will Update my answer

Comment: thanks a lot, I am waiting for your answer with excitement

Comment: @FurkanGürsoy please check it i have updated , if you have found any difficulties do not hesitate to leave comments

Comment: @FurkanGürsoy if you see that my answer is useful please vote it up and click on the green button to accept it